# Fiware-skuld are deleting all VM in the tenant instead of user's VMs

Tags: fiware, fiware-skuld

I am using fiware-skuld and I have a question about it.

Why are the VMs of the tenant deleted instead of the VM of the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the resources (with the exception of key pairs) are owned by a tenant, not
by a user. This is true also for virtual machines. The field about the user is informative and only indicates what user created the VM.

In FIWARE, users have their own tenants and are the resources of those
tenants which are released.

A user can participate in other tenant (project) and in this case is a bad
idea to delete the VM. It is owned for the project in which the user was working in, not by the user.